# table already exist exception in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

i have downloaded `FOSUserBundle` and configure it but i am facing the issue in updating the schema using following command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

i am getting following exception for my existing database

[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  The table with name 'hub.tb_business_info' already exists.

`tb_business_info` is my existing table which was created by doctrine

so how would i create the `User` table in my existing database

Updated , here is my ORM defination

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend checking your ORM definitions and check to see if you accidently used the table name `tb_business_info ` more than once. This probably isn't related to FOSUserBundle because it uses the default table name `fos_user` unless you configured it to something else and then you may have to manually drop the table from your database.

Comment: @KenHannel you are right